# PhpStorm and Docker - Unable to configure the PHP interpreter (Failed to parse script validation output)

Tags: php, docker-compose, phpstorm

I'm using Docker composer with a PHP. When trying to set the interpreter I choose Docker compose, I choose the PHP container and then it fails with the error "Failed to parse script validation output".

If I execute `php -v` inside the container everything seems fine, I tried to set the full path of the PHP executable but I got the same error.

PHPStorm is 2018.2 and php

```
php -v
PHP 7.1.22 (cli) (built: Sep 15 2018 03:39:59) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: What are you IDE & PHP versions ?

Comment: @LazyOne updated!

Comment: Well ... such issue was closed in 2018.1.6 from what I can see from PhpStorm Issue Tracker. What 2018.2.x version in particular you are using? There was https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-41186 ticket that was marked as duplicate of https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-41002. Please check what your `idea.log` file has to say about that (`Help | Show Log in XXX`)

Comment: Try this solution: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000335990/comments/360000052099